# Unity enums referenced by inspector becoming out of order when extended

Tags: c#, serialization, enums, unity-game-engine

### Issue:

enum's referenced by gameobject scripts via inspector variables become out of order when the enum has new entries added before the referenced index.

### Details:

So I have multiple systems such as item lists, localisation strings, etc which are dynamically built by parsing external files. This parsing creates enum's which are used to reference the items by gameobject's via script inspector variables. Here's the parsed output by my localisation system as an example:

```
    public enum LocaleID 
    {
        LocalisedStrings_ENGB,
        LocalisedStrings_ENUS,

        //...

        MAX,
    }

    public enum StringID 
    {
        String_EMPTY,
        String_Inventory,
        String_Recipes,
        String_Tools,
        String_Journal,

        //...
    }

public static class LocalisedStrings
{
    private static string[] SCLocalisedStrings_ENGB = 
    {
        "",
        "Inventory",
        "Recipes",
        "Tools",
        "Journal",

        //...
    }

    private static LocaleID currentLocale = (LocaleID)0;
    private static string[] activeSC = SCLocalisedStrings_ENGB;

    public static void SetLocale(LocaleID newLocale)
    {
        currentLocale = newLocale;
        switch(newLocale)
        {
            case LocaleID.LocalisedStrings_ENGB:
                activeSC = SCLocalisedStrings_ENGB;
            break;
            case LocaleID.LocalisedStrings_ENUS:
                activeSC = SCLocalisedStrings_ENUS;
            break;
        }
    }

    //entry interface: 
    public static string Get(StringID stringID)
    {
        return activeSC[(int)stringID];
    }
}
```

This simply returns the string via the enum index based off the set locale.
So I'd have something such as a name of an NPC exposed on a character as:

```
[SerializeField]
public StringID SpeakerTitle;
```

and set that through the inspector.

The issue is a rather obvious and expected one - if the enum is parsed differently, for example an extra entry is added to the top (for example for sorting purposes) or removed (for cleaning up obsolete entries), then all referenced enum's will become out of order by 1 spot since they'll be referencing the index of the enum entry.

A simple solution would be to impose a rule of only adding to the end and never removing entries that become stale. This becomes quite wasteful, so is obviously not very preferable.

What are suggested solutions to this issue? Any examples of how others approach this rather common situation? My preference would of course be something which could be sorted and new entries added anywhere, but we can't have everything we want :)

Comment: Internally Unity only stores the enum values, so if you extend the enum anywhere but the end you shift the numbers around and Unity will change the selected enum according to its stored value, not the enum's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify explicit numeric values for the entries:

```
public enum StringID 
{
    String_EMPTY = 0,
    String_Inventory = 1,
    String_Recipes = 2,
    String_Tools = 3,
    String_Journal = 4,

    //...
}
```

That way the ordering is entirely irrelevant to the values. Note that you can do this retrospectively, or in a "just in time" way when you need to make what would otherwise be a breaking change.

(I'd personally get rid of the `String_` prefix as well, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, I've now taken this approach for all the naive/internal code referenced implementations, and I've implemented a stage in the parser for external data to do a compare and track pre-existing entries to retain their index. 

I must admit this was my fallback, or "plan b" approach -- it's how I'd usually approach stacked enum or bitfield categorisation and indexing due to my over-exposure of UE3 over the last 8 years. I was hoping I was missing out on some other obvious approach or usage pattern to better manage this common situation, but looks like this is still the best route!

Comment: You can do this, but will the end product quality survive multiple developers adding the n+1 value to the enum in separate branches?

Comment: @theMayer: It would be very easy to add a unit test to make sure all the values are unique, so you spot the problem on merge.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an explicit map rather than a naked array; for example:

```
private static Dictionary<StringID,string> SCLocalisedStrings_ENGB = 
    new Dictionary<StringID,string>
{
    {StringID.String_EMPTY, ""},
    {StringID.String_Inventory, "Inventory"},
    //...
};
```

and get the value via something like:

```
string val;
return LocaleStrings.TryGetValue(key, out val) ? val : DefaultStrings[key];
```

Well... actually, I'd probably have the translations in external files as key/value pairs, but... meh.

Note: you could always *put* the dictionary data back into an ordered array; but having the explicit map prevents order from mattering.

Comment: I like the data structure of storing in a key/value pair for the internal data for localisation, a bit more convenient for a few systems.
However unless I'm missing something, this approach doesn't address the parsing situation of adding/removing entries in the referenced key field (eg, externally something is still referencing the StringID of n which could change index positionally if it gets bumped)?