# Is there an elegant way to preserve enum names in Unity scene files?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

As others have pointed out, if you assign a value of an `enum` in the Unity inspector, [it will store the numerical value of the enum rather than the name](https://forum.unity.com/threads/enum-becomes-int-in-inspector.527822/). This results in problems if enums later are edited, as often happens during development.

The [oft-proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26176463/1472222) is to add numerical keys to the enum, as such:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    Entry1 = 0,
    Entry2 = 1,
    ...
}
```

This doesn't survive contact with multiple developers very well. Suppose *Developer A* adds three items to the enum, and *Developer B* (not coordinating with *Developer A*) also adds a couple of enum values. They now do not agree on which values are used for `2` and `3`. Unfortunately, Unity won't have any idea that this is even a problem, and a peer review seems like an unreliable way to detect these types of conflicts.

Is there a way to force Unity to store the **name** of the `enum` rather than its numerical value?

Comment: This is why enums should be numbered further apart and any new sections added at the ends!! You can get enum names but it’s way less efficient

Comment: I'm not sure anyone is good enough to know how many categories there are, or even what numbering scheme might be useful. And I don't know what type of efficiency you're referring to - the compiler will fill in numerical values during compilation. It most certainly is not efficient to have a developer try to make a manual translation between a meaningless number and an enum. This is an issue between source code written in c# and the way the Unity inspector handles references to the source.

Comment: Unity probably should serialize the name instead of the underlying value.  However, that would likely require a change to the serializer, which may cause additional processing time in unexpected places.  Not sure if the serializer/deserializer is used during runtime, but that would be a good enough reason to store the underlying value over storing strings which require more physical space and parsing to deserialize.  I would argue that the developers should not be stepping on each others feet.

Comment: Well @theMayer i never said use numbers in code. I said you can get the name of an enum but storing as string  and converting is less efficient and prone to other issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is more related to not Unity C# code, but hope can help you.

If you want to have no numbers in data that storing to have the possibility to have something more unique, you can use another approach here like Constants class. Here is an example:

```
public class Constants
{
    public readonly string Entry1 = "entry_code_1";
    public readonly string Entry2 = "entry_code_2";
    public readonly string Entry3 = "entry_code_3";
    //and others
}
```

To use it simply write:

```
var value = EntryConstants.Entry1;
```

In case it is constants, it will not explode your memory with new instances, and performance here should also be okay.
The problem is that C# does not support string enums yet, and it is a reason why this dirty hack with Constants class works best.

You can also use the `.ToString()` method and `Enum.Parse<MyEnum>(str)`, but it is less flexible and has a problem with creating new instances of the string

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I’m looking for something that works with Unity specifically. This is not an issue with regular C# code.